# Entity Framework: lambda parameter to DbPropertyEntry or DbReferenceEntry

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

Working with EF6, in a generic method, I am trying to set some property values like so:

```
    protected void MyFunc<T>(T entity, params Expression<Func<T, dynamic>>[] properiesToCopy) where T: class
    {    
        foreach (var propertyEntry in properiesToCopy)
        {
            context.Entry(_entityCopy).Property(propertyEntry ).CurrentValue = context.Entry(entity).Property(propertyEntry).CurrentValue;
        }
    }
```

Now, I would like to use the same function for reference types of the entity, but then I would have to use `DbEntityEntry.Reference` function.

How can I know whether the lambda expression (named propertyEntry above) referes to a DbPropertyEntry or to a DbReferenceEntry? Or can my function perform the same action in a better way?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, I just had to use `DbEntityEntry.Member` function, which will work for scalar types, reference types and even collections. However, this only works with a string parameter: so I took the method [TryParsePath](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework/Internal/DbHelpers.cs) from the entity framework source code that converts a Lambda path to a string path.

Then I could do:

```
        string path;
        foreach (var memberEntry in membersToCopy)
        {
            if (!Utils.TryParsePath(memberEntry .Body, out path))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Include path not valid", "path");
            }
            context.Entry(_entityCopy).Member(path).CurrentValue = context.Entry(entity).Member(path).CurrentValue;
        }
```